# How to handle invalid encoded url in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I like to know how sites like Google handle invalid encoded URLs param.
for example:

- https://google.com/%c0
- https://instagram.com/%c0

I've tried to cater to the react-router-dom using the path "*". However, when I go to the **`localhost:3000/%c0`** it's not captured but straight away goes to an Error page with the following error:

```
URIError: Failed to decode param '/%c0'
    at decodeURIComponent (<anonymous>)
    at decode_param (<ProjectPath>\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:172:12)
```

I've also tried putting **console.log** before the **render()** function in **index.js** to see if it's even reached there and it doesn't.

So right now, I believe this could not be handled on the application level. Or I just don't know how.

Any help is really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Which react-router version are you using ?

Comment: Hi, what are you trying to achieve? What's wrong with an Error Page?

Comment: @MaulikPatel I'm using v6.11.1

Comment: @stepeusz It would be best if I can show a custom error page rather than just a page text of error, and shortly after, redirect user to the home/login page

Comment: @RahmanNilam you can use react-router-dom library

Comment: @AfzalK. I am using it as per my post

Comment: you are not using it in correct way, or better use decodeURIComponent, decode URL, return original string, then check against valid list of urls and redirect

Comment: or Instead of using the path route use <Redirect> component

Comment: @AfzalK. I'm interested to know how to implement this decodeURIComponent?
regarding the redirect method for React-Router, it's not possible. Because the error happened outside of the application/code level - meaning, my index.js which have the render() function is not even reached. you can try run a simple create-react-app project and try use localhost:3000/%c0 and see what's the response.

Comment: Also, i understand that this is an edge case. Nobody sane would use invalid url, let alone an encoded one, but it's in the requirement of my project to handle this case.